# How to handle many WHERE clause with PHP PDO that comes from Ajax variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have a problem here on handling multi WHERE clause using PDO PHP. My Ajax code sends two variable which is one for input text for livesearch and one for dropdown menu. Here is my code.

Ajax Code: index.php

```
<p style="text-align: center">Enter your search here: <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Enter your search here">&nbsp;&nbsp;
Select education level: <select id="edulevel">
<option value="PHD">PHD</option>
<option value="MASTER">MASTER</option>
<option value="DEGREE">DEGREE</option></select></p>    
<div id="contentBox" class="login, reminder" style="margin:0px auto; width:95%; overflow-y: auto; height:304px;">


<div id="result" class="login"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /*
    setInterval(function(){
        //alert('Refreshing database');
        $("#result").load("res.php", "update=true").fadeIn("slow").text("Refreshing Database");
    }, 10000);
    */


    function update() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userres.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                if (parseInt(data) == 0) {
                    $("#result").css({ color: "red" }).text("offline");
                } else {
                    $("#result").css({ color: "green" }).text("online");
                }
            }
        });    // properly end the ajax() invocation
    }


    function ajaxSearchUpdater(){
        $("#result").show();
        var x = $("#search").val();
        var y = $("#edulevel").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'userres.php',
            data:'q='+x+'&e='+y,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                $("#result").html(data)
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        ajaxSearchUpdater();               // fires on document.ready
        $("#search").keyup(function() {
            ajaxSearchUpdater();           // your function call
        });
        $("#edulevel").click(function() {
            ajaxSearchUpdater();           // your function call
        });
    });
</script>
```

For my php and database code:userres.php

```
//print_r($_GET);
$q=$_POST['q'];
if(isset($_POST['e'])){
    $e=$_POST['e'];
    echo $q;
    echo $e;
}


$query="SELECT *
            FROM viewlibrary
            WHERE 
                studentname LIKE :q OR
                matricno LIKE :q OR
                title LIKE :q OR
                education_level LIKE :q OR
                programme LIKE :q OR
                serialno LIKE :q OR
                education_level = :e
            ORDER BY studentname ASC";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bindValue(':q','%'.$q.'%');
$stmt->bindValue(':e',$e, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$a = 0; 

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $r=$stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<table class='tablesorter' id='myTable' style='width:97%; table-border: 1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>No.</th>";
        echo "<th>No.Matric</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Programme</th>";
        echo "<th>Title</th>";
        echo "<th>Education Level</th>";
        echo "<th>Serial Number</th>";
        echo "<th>Availability</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

    foreach($r as $row){

            echo "<tr align='center'><td>". ($a+1) ."</td><td>". $row['matricno'] ."</td><td>". $row['studentname'] ."</td><td>". $row['programme'] ."</td><td>". $row['title'] ."</td><td>". $row['education_level'] ."</td><td>". $row['serialno'] ."</td><td>". $row['bavailable'] ."</td></tr>";
            $a++;
            //echo $row['education_level'];
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
    echo "<p align='center'>Nothing to show you :( I am really sorry for this T_T </p>";
}


?>
```

The problem here is I want to make my table to show list of data that only with suitable education level which is 'Degree', 'Master', 'PHD' that depends on the dropdown selection by the user. I did echo my variable that comes from ajax and it shows what I clicked but I cant seems to find a way how to handle these query. Most of that WHERE condition is for livesearch and I wonder how should I put condition for my dropdown list.

Comment: You can't use same placeholder multiple times!!

Comment: @Saty umm what do you mean by placeholder? are you refering to html placeholder?

Comment: The `:q` and `:e` are placeholders. Have you considered using full text searching? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: oh I didn't know that :( then how do I want to use my dropdown variable for query?

Comment: @chris85 I have not heard of it before and well i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Since i can't use 2 placeholder, i wonder if i can use separate query which is one for livesearch and one for dropdown menu variable, then execute them both?

Comment: oh nevermind i got it. Thanks anyway :) Consider this problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the search by the education_level that user have chosen.

```
SELECT *
FROM viewlibrary
WHERE 
    education_level = :e AND 
    (studentname LIKE :q1 OR
    matricno LIKE :q2 OR
    title LIKE :q3 OR
    education_level LIKE :q4 OR
    programme LIKE :q5 OR
    serialno LIKE :q6)
ORDER BY studentname ASC
```

Also do not try to use the same named parameter twice in a single SQL statement, for example

```
<?php 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE  some_value > :value OR some_value < :value'; 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute( array( ':value' => 3 ) ); 
?>
```

this will return no rows and no error -- you must use each parameter once and only once. Apparently this is expected behavior (according to this bug report: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33886) because of portability issues.